# How to check if function pointer passed from C is non-NULL

Tags: c, rust, ffi

Example code below

The Rust part:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn call_c_function(value: i32, fun: fn(i32) -> i32) -> i32 {
    fun(value)
}
```

And the C part:

```
int32_t call_c_function(int32_t value, int32_t (*fun)(int32_t));

int32_t triple(int32_t x)
{
    return x*3;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int32_t value = 3;
    int32_t result = call_c_function(value, triple);

    printf("%d tripled is %d\n", value, result);

    call_c_function(0, NULL);  // Crash here

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Of course second call of `call_c_function` will crash.
Rust compiler will not complain about unsafe code inside `call_c_function`, because from rust point of view this code is safe. Also it's not allowed to simply write:

```
if !fun.is_null() {
    fun(value)
}
```

because `fun` type is `fn(i32) -> i32` (it's not a pointer).

So my question is, how I can protect `call_c_function` against NULL pointer dereference? Is there any way to check if callback passed from C is not valid?

Maybe I have to change `call_c_function` definition?

Comment: Yes, just check if fun == NULL.  Or zero, if NULL is not a thing in rust.  Mind you, I don't know rust very well, but that's how you would do it in C.

Comment: See here: http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html#the-%22nullable-pointer-optimization%22

Comment: @Adrian Thx, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `Option<...>` to represent nullable function pointers. It is incorrect to have a NULL value for a value of type `fn(...)` so the `Option` wrapper is required for cases like this.

For example,

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn call_c_function(value: i32, fun: Option<fn(i32) -> i32>) -> i32 {
    if let Some(f) = fun {
        f(value)
    }
}
```

However, there's one extra point: `fun` is a C function, but the type `fn(...)` is a Rust function. They're not directly compatible (e.g. their calling conventions differ). One needs to use the `extern "C" fn(...)` (a.k.a. `extern fn(...)`) type when interacting with C function pointers:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn call_c_function(value: i32, fun: Option<extern "C" fn(i32) -> i32>) -> i32 {
    if let Some(f) = fun {
        f(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrapping the function pointer argument in `Option<...>` does not seem to work with cbindgen. The generated header file will contain a structure type instead of a function pointer.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to the cbindgen problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can compare a pointer that has been generated by unsafe code against `std::ptr::null()`

e.g.

```
let pw = libc::getpwnam(username.as_ptr() as *const i8);
if std::ptr::null() != pw ...
```

`null()` on Linux is `0 as *const T` I'm not sure if that is universal.

Comment: This does not work with *function* pointers, which are non-nullable, as huon's answer explains.