# How does a repr(C) type handle Option?

Tags: rust

I have this C code:

```c
typedef void (*f_t)(int a);

struct Foo {
        f_t f;
};

extern void f(struct Foo *);
```

[bindgen](https://github.com/Yamakaky/rust-bindgen) generates the following Rust code (I have removed unimportant details):

```
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Foo {
    pub f: ::std::option::Option<extern "C" fn(a: ::std::os::raw::c_int)>,
}
```

I do not understand why `Option` is here. Obviously that Rust `enum` and C pointer are not the same thing on the bit level, so how does the Rust compiler handle this?

When I call the C `f` function and pass a pointer to a Rust struct `Foo`, does the compiler convert `Foo_rust` to `Foo_C` and then only pass a pointer to `Foo_C` to `f`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [The Rust Programming Language chapter on FFI](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html#the-nullable-pointer-optimization) (emphasis mine):

> Certain types are defined to not be null. This includes references (`&T`, `&mut T`), boxes (`Box<T>`), and function pointers (`extern "abi" fn()`). When interfacing with C, pointers that might be null are often used. As a special case, a generic enum that contains exactly two variants, one of which contains no data and the other containing a single field, is eligible for the "nullable pointer optimization". When such an enum is instantiated with one of the non-nullable types, it is represented as a single pointer, and the non-data variant is represented as the null pointer. **So `Option<extern "C" fn(c_int) -> c_int>` is how one represents a nullable function pointer using the C ABI.**

Said another way:

> Obviously that Rust enum and C pointer are not the same thing on the bit level

They actually are, when the `Option` contains a specific set of types.

---

See also:

- [Can I use the "null pointer optimization" for my own non-pointer types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30414068/155423)
- [What is the overhead of Rust's Option type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16504643/155423)
- [How to check if function pointer passed from C is non-NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31481102/155423)